# Excel 2010 error message when opening .xlsm files

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to open a .xlsm file in Excel 2010 when I receive the error:

"There was a problem sending the command to the program"

Once Excel is open, I am able to open the file, but if Excel is closed, it spits out the error (Operating system: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.  Hardware: Dell Latitude E6540).

"Solutions" that I have tried to implement but don't fix the problem.

- Uncheck the "Ignore other applications that use Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE).
- Repair Office 2010.
- Uninstall and reinstall Office 2010
- Saving to the computer and opening them locally instead of on the network.

This problem occurs with all .xlsm files and all of the files have macros in them.

Other users on other systems have no errors opening the same files.

Any help and/or comment is welcome and appreciated!

Comment: Have you repaired excel?

Comment: I have tried to repair the entire office suit, including excel, and it has not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:
1.Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
2.Click Default Programs.
3.Click Associate a file type or protocol with a specific program.
4.Select Microsoft Excel Worksheet, and then click change program.
5.Under Recommended Programs, click Microsoft Excel.
6.If Excel does not appear in this list, click Browse, locate the Excel installation folder, click Excel.exe, and then click Excel.
?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and it has not worked.

Comment: @CameronSkywalker, just to be clear: you did that for the .xlsm file type, right?

Comment: And there's this link to Microsoft: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/error-message-for-excel-there-was-a-problem/179b45cd-2fab-4621-9b9b-db80eda03aaf

Comment: Yes, for the .xlsm file type as well as any other file types that I wanted open with Excel.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all add-ins?

Comment: Yes, I disabled all Excel and COM add-ins and it still did not work.

Comment: @CameronSkywalker, then I'm out of ideas.  I had the same issue has you a couple of months ago, and it turned out to be an add-in.  I'm sorry I couldn't help.  Other than a complete reinstall of the OS and MS Office, I don't know what else you can try.

Comment: Thanks for the help @BillOer.  Yes, I have tried a complete reinstall as well and that still did not help...  I have found a temporary solution for the problem, however, the fact that the complete reinstall didn't solve the problem leads me to believe that it is something that is in the operating system or the hardware that is the problem and not a setting in Excel.